# will formatting a hard drive from one computer allow me to use it in another?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive

The hard drive on my computer at home is actively dying. I have a ext hard drive that I have everything backed up to. At work, we have two computers, one of which died and my manager doesn't plan on fixing (he's also allowing me to take parts from it.) I have the hard drive in the working computer at work and plan on formatting it and swapping in with the dying one at home. Will this work? what issues could I run into? Are there additional steps I need to take?
Work computer is running windows 7 home computer is running windows 10

Answer (score 1):

You can use the disk at home, but if it is formatted there will be no operating system on it - if you want to use an OS you have to install it on the new disk.

Comment: >if you want to use an OS you have to install in on the new disk.   How do I go about that? Is there any way to do it with the backup I have made? The current computer only has one SATA port.

Comment: @akp1111, just Google for a tutorial. With modern versions of Windows it's quite a simple procedure, but too lenghty to put it here (and it was already described many times on the Internet, so just search)

Answer (score 0):

">if you want to use an OS you have to install in on the new disk.   How do I go about that? Is there any way to do it with the backup I have made? The current computer only has one SATA port"

You can't simply copy windows from one disk to another. You must use drive image software like "Paragon" free edition boot CD that u load from DVD drive as computer boots.  You can take image of current windows disk and write as image file to external HDD then switch to new HDD and read the image file back to the new disk.

This should work provided you have enough space on the external drive to hold the entire C:\ contents as an image file.

If the used space or amount of data on your old HDD is big (over 100+ GB's) then this may take a very long time (a very very long time if using less that USB3 external drive and ports) to copy the image back and forth with paragon so in that case I simply recommed to do a fresh install of windows and install drivers and programs again.

You can think ahead a little, after you install all drivers you can take then an image with paragon for nextime you have these kinds of issues. An image of a fresh install should easily backup to around 20GB of space but once you add many programs it may become much larger.